# problem with Facebook scraper can't see my webpage

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I've got a server with several websites hosted in it, I've been having a problem for two weeks and it's the following:

I started noticing that "Likes" on posts where less than before and I noticed that when I shared a post or liked it in the thumbnail it said "Error 404" and displayed the default message that my server gives when you target the IP instead of one of the pages. A couple of weeks ago it worked perfectly so I don't know what could've happened.

More info: all the pages are wordpress and all of them use v4.0 except one of them that is using v3.9.2 I think it's not a wordpress problem, I have other wordpress based sites on other server and they work good, it's like it was a dns problem or something. have you ever encountered a problem like this?

I don't know if I've explained myself very well so if you have any questions feel free to ask.

More info++:

This is what the srapper sees:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<title></title>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#001C66">

<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="img/construction.gif" alt="under construction"></td>
    <td valign="bottom">
<font size="+2" face="verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif">
This domain has just been registered for one of our customers!</font><br><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif">
Domain registration and webhosting at best prices.</font><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
    <td align="center">
   </td>


  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

That's clearly not my webpage :P, but if I use wget or something like that I do get the correct html.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the debug tool say about what your URL is returning to Facebook?

Comment: It says this: "Object at URL 'http://www.aishawari.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided." The problem is that the original website does have all those attributes, but facebook can't reach the real website only the default index.html in the server which of course doesn't have any of those metas

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix it so the correct data is returned to Facebook

Comment: The meta-data is correct, it worked a couple of weeks ago and now it doesn't work for any posts in my page even the old ones. Also I've looked them by hand and they are set correctly, that's not the problem, the problem is that my server is not letting facebook access each website and facebook can't reach the real content.